# Session ID does not work with Express

Tags: node.js, express, session, npm, postman

I am building a website using MEAN stack, currently working on backend using express. When I make a user, a session id called 'req.session.userId' is generated. For testing purpose, I am testing on '/logout' route, if req.session.userId exists, then I return string 'working'. It seems like everything works on Postman but not on the browser side.

This is the output from Postman. It returns string 'working'

[image: Postman]

This is from browser, it returns string 'not working' when `sessionId` does not exist

[image: Postman]

This is my Logout function from controller that gets called by router

```
exports.Logout = function(req,res,next){
 if (req.session.userId){
  res.send("working");
 else{
  res.send("this isn't working!");
 }
}
```

This is from app.js for storing session

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'hardworking cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new mongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db //store sessionid when user logs in
    })
}));
```

I am really confused. It works on Postman but not on my browser. Am I possibly missing something?

Comment: Postman does API calls, the software save cookie created by backend when it's send to the frontend. Can you provide a screenshot of the cookie content returned after logging in from browser ?

Comment: Okay. I don't see cookie that is saved on Chrome dev tool. On my mongodb database, I'm saving sesssionID when a user logs in, and make deleted when a user logs out. This is the session id that is saved on my Mongodb; { "_id" : "URond477aXWdyVBU5lz_IQbv4RN_SSEL", "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"userId\":\"5b253d83b599682d0898a0ef\"}", "expires" : ISODate("2018-06-30T17:08:35.385Z") }When a user successfully creates an account, it would login with sessionId. Inside creating a user, I'm setting req.session.userId = user._id

Comment: 1st thing you need to do is make sure you set session the in req.session when user login. 
Btw You need to deploy your Angular project in express public folder, if not there will be no cookies stored in the browser.

Comment: I think the issue is sessionId will change on 'post' request. On get request, sessionID persists, but whenever i do post, sessionID is different

Comment: Sorry, my apology. I didn't realize post from Postman will give different sessionId than you would post on a browser. I am very new to web development...sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problem, we all starts somewhere. Perhaps checking this course https://www.udemy.com/angular-2-and-nodejs-the-practical-guide/ or https://www.udemy.com/understand-nodejs/ will help you understand.